# Google storage with signed url

Tags: google-cloud-storage, pre-signed-url

How to upload file with content-type `mutlipart/formdata  ---boundaryString` 
using [signed url](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) of google storage  ?

The problem i am facing is when we use browser to upload a file the browser puts the content type of `mutlipart/formdata  ---boundaryString`  where `boundaryString` is a dynamic part of the content-type header value.

Now since the google signing method require content-type to be a part of signature. Generating a signed url became impossible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For uploading using a form on the web, GCS provides an alternative to a regular signed URL called a "policy document." A policy document is a signed upload policy filled with a description of what sorts of uploads are and are not okay and are included as one of the parameters of your form post.

See https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object#policydocument for details.

So, for example, an HTML form that allowed uploads would look like this:

```
<form action="http://travel-maps.storage.googleapis.com"
 method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="key" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="bucket" value="travel-maps">
  <input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg">
  <input type="hidden" name="GoogleAccessId" value="1234567890123@developer.gserviceaccount.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="bucket-owner-read">
  <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://www.example.com/success_notification.html">
  <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjogIjIwMTAtMDYtMTZUMTE6MTE6MTFaIiwNCiAiY29uZGl0aW9ucyI6IFsNCiAgWyJzdGFydHMtd2l0aCIsICJrZXkiLCAiIiBdLA0KICB7ImFjbCI6ICJidWNrZXQtb3duZXItcmVhZCIgfSwNCiAgeyJidWNrZXQiOiAidHJhdmVsLW1hcHMifSwNCiAgeyJzdWNjZXNzX2FjdGlvbl9yZWRpcmVjdCI6ICJodHRwOi8vd3d3LmV4YW1wbGUuY29tL3N1Y2Nlc3Nfbm90aWZpY2F0aW9uLmh0bWwiIH0sDQogIFsiZXEiLCAiQ29udGVudC1UeXBlIiwgImltYWdlL2pwZWciIF0sDQogIFsiY29udGVudC1sZW5ndGgtcmFuZ2UiLCAwLCAxMDAwMDAwXQ0KICBdDQp9">
  <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="BSAMPLEaASAMPLE6SAMPLE+SAMPPLEqSAMPLEPSAMPLE+SAMPLEgSAMPLEzCPlgWREeF7oPGowkeKk7J4WApzkzxERdOQmAdrvshKSzUHg8Jqp1lw9tbiJfE2ExdOOIoJVmGLoDeAGnfzCd4fTsWcLbal9sFpqXsQI8IQi1493mw=">
  <input name="file" type="file">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

The "policy" field contains a description of what the user can upload. It's a JSON document that's been base 64 encoded. Unencoded, it looks like this:

```
{"expiration": "2010-06-16T11:11:11Z",
 "conditions": [
  ["starts-with", "$key", "" ],
  {"acl": "bucket-owner-read" },
  {"bucket": "travel-maps"},
  {"success_action_redirect": "http://www.example.com/success_notification.html" },
  ["eq", "$Content-Type", "image/jpeg" ],
  ["content-length-range", 0, 1000000]
  ]
}
```

The "signature" field works like a signed URL would, except that you're signing the policy, not the request. It's the base64 encoding of the rsa/sha-256 of the policy document.

Comment: Got it... but can we have resumable upload using policy document strategy?

Comment: @Bhuvan Ever found the answer on whether resumable upload is possible with use of policy?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need to use signedURLs mechanism to avoid from "uploaded file size limitation" problem. However, I don't understand how you decide the values of the "policy" and signature in your html code. How did you encode your JSON file and obtain corresponding values? Besides, is it enough to use just corresponding JSON file and add some information into HTML form object?

Comment: It's documented here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/signatures#policy-document

Once you've formed your policy document, base64 encode it and make it the value of a hidden form field named `policy`.